# How to generate random time series data including February with 29 days?

Tags: python, arrays, date, datetime

I have used the following codes to generate a random rainfall data from 1950 to 2009 with known probability, mean and standard deviations. But, I have been suffering from iterating the days of February as 29 days in the leap years. And, also I was trying to save the output in a text file, but it gives an error message like

> TypeError: float argument required, not numpy.string_

Can anyone please help me out?

My code:

```
import numpy as np
import random
import itertools
import datetime

dry =[0.33,0.27,0.32,0.41,0.42,0.45,0.57,0.52,0.45,0.39,0.37,0.37]
wet = [0.66,0.72,0.67,0.58,0.57,0.54,0.42,0.47,0.54,0.60,0.62,0.62]
d2d_tran = [0.56,0.50,0.58,0.62,0.63,0.67,0.73,0.66,0.60,0.56,0.57,0.62]
w2w_tran = [0.78,0.80,0.79,0.73,0.72,0.72,0.63,0.64,0.66,0.71,0.74,0.76]
mu = [3.71, 4.46, 4.11, 2.94, 3.00, 2.87, 2.31, 2.44, 2.56, 3.45, 4.32, 4.12]
sigma = [6.72,7.92,7.49,6.57,6.09,5.53,4.38,4.69,4.31,5.71,7.64,7.54]
days = [31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31]
rain = []

for y in xrange(0,60):
    for m in xrange(0,12):
        random_num = np.random.rand(days[m])
        if random.random() <= dry[m]:
            random_num[0] = 0
        else:
            r = abs(random.gauss(mu[m],sigma[m]))
            random_num[0] = r
        for i in xrange(1,days[m]):
            if random_num[i-1] == 0:
                if random_num[i] <= d2d_tran[m]:
                    random_num[i] = 0
                else:
                    r = abs(random.gauss(mu[m],sigma[m]))
                    random_num[i] = r
            else:
                if random_num[i] <= w2w_tran[m]:
                    r = abs(random.gauss(mu[m],sigma[m]))
                    random_num[i] = r
                else:
                    random_num[i] = 0
        rain.append(random_num)
rain_series = []
for j in itertools.chain.from_iterable(rain):
    rain_series.append(j)
y = np.array(rain_series).reshape(-1, 1) 

date_series = []
def generate_dates(start_date, end_date):
return (start_date + datetime.timedelta(days=d) for d in xrange((end_date - start_date).days + 1))
start_date = datetime.date(1950, 1, 1)
end_date = datetime.date(2009, 12, 16)
for current_date in generate_dates(start_date, end_date):
    f = current_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    date_series.append(f)
z = np.array(date_series).reshape(-1, 1)

#### Here I have 365x60 = 21900 rainfall values, that is why I had to 
####set the end_date upto (2009,12,16). If
#### the February days for leap years can be set as 29 in days[] of 
####rain_series than this problem would be solved.

data = np.concatenate((z,y), axis=1)
print data
data1 = data.reshape((21900,2))
np.savetxt('Random Rainfall Data.txt', data1)
#### I want to shape data in two columns like dates and rainfall.
#### And than, save it into a text file. But, it provides an error!!!
```

Comment: use `np.savetxt('Random Rainfall Data.txt', data1, fmt="%s")`

Comment: Thank you, HYRY. I have got it.

Comment: Hi, is there any way to generate random numbers in Box-Cox distribution using known mean, std.dev and lambda? Say, I have used random.gauss(mu,sigma) and random.lognormvariate(mu, sigma) to generate normally and log-normally distributed random variables. How can I do the same for Box-Cox case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `calendar.monthrange()` to get the number of days of a month.

```
for year in xrange(1950,2020):
    for month in xrange(1,13):
        day_num = calendar.monthrange(year, month)[1]
        random_num = np.random.rand(day_num)

        ...
```

Comment: I have declared the days of month as "days = [31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31]" for generating the rain_series. I want to iterate the second value of the list (28 for February) as like it will be 29 instead of 28 in every 4 years.

Comment: It's just perfect!! Thank you, Leonardo.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the data writing problem, you must add a third argument. It depends on your specific problem:

```
np.savetxt('test.txt', a, '%s') # Example
```

See [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html) for more formatting info.

Comment: Not really, don't have many time today (Exams week). Just helping as much as I can.